# Error en Xcode con Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

estoy haciendo una App usando phonegap/cordova, al momento de ejecutar el emulador de iOS con xcode me da el error de "Build Failed".

ejecute el comando: cordova prepare ios

Este me generó un proyecto de xcode el cual intento darle ejecutar y me marca el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya la firmaste?

Comment: Estoy siguiendo unos videos de udemy de fernando herrera y menciona que no hace falta firmar si se hará debug, al publicarla en las tiendas si sera necesario, pero desconozco del tema, es la primera vez que intento ejecutar una app en xcode.

Comment: Si solo vas a debugger debes hacer `prepare > for debug` y luego correrla seleccionando el emulador

Comment: Aceptaste los términos y condiciones en tu cuenta de Apple Developer? Luego de eso revisa los Profiles y Certificados y los instalas en tu Mac.